# Prolog - List manipulation, if--then--else, recursion

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

**The goal:**

```
rovarsprak([104, 101, 106], B).
B = [104,111,104,101,106,111,106]
```

*[104, 101, 106] = "hej"*
*B = "hohejoj"*

**Currently:**

```
rovarsprak([104, 101, 106], B).
B = [104,111,104,106,111,106]
```

*[104, 101, 106] = "hej"*
*B = "hohjoj"*

*(E.g. I'm loosing the middle, non-affected, element (101 = "e").)*

**The code:**

```
voal(97).   % 97 = a
voal(111).  % 111 = o
voal(117).  % 117 = u
voal(101).  % 101 = e
voal(105).  % 105 = i
voal(121).  % 121 = y

isLowerCase(A) :-
  A > 96,   % small A is 97
  A < 123.  % small Z is 122

rovarsprak([], []).
rovarsprak([A|AS], [X,Y,Z|ZS]) :-
  A = X, A = Z, Y = 111,
  isLowerCase(A),
  (\+ voal(A))                    % if
  -> rovarsprak(AS, ZS)           % then
    ; rovarsprak(AS, [X,Y,Z|ZS]). % else
```

I feel like I'm missing the point here...

Comment: If you use characters (like `a`) in place of character codes, your program would be much more readable.  `A > 96` would have to be replaced by `A @>= a` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in else case where you call recursively your predicate without having instantiate any of X,Y,Z. You should instantiate X=A so your list will not ignore A as it does now. So the only change you need is adding `A=X` after `;`  and call `rovarsprak(AS, [Y,Z|ZS]).` since X is instantiated:

```
rovarsprak([], []).
rovarsprak([A|AS], [X,Y,Z|ZS]) :-
  A = X, A = Z, Y = 111,
  isLowerCase(A),
  (\+ voal(A))                    % if
  -> rovarsprak(AS, ZS)           % then
    ; A=X,rovarsprak(AS, [Y,Z|ZS]). % else
```

Example:

```
?- rovarsprak([104, 101, 106], B).
B = [104, 111, 104, 101, 106, 111, 106].
```